# Parameterised item in MSBuild project

Tags: msbuild

We have a C# custom property applied at the assembly level to a few hundred projects in the one solution. It takes a number of arguments which are a mixture of constants, values supplied at build time, and others inserted by code generation. **The attribute may also be applied more than once per assembly.** I'm looking to automate away some of the fragility in this setup. All the projects use csproj SDK XML.

The `<AssemblyAttribute>` element in a csproj `<ItemGroup>` looks ideal for this, but the nature of the parameters to this attribute makes it verbose to write this way. Ideally I'd like to just be able to specify the bit that varies per project, something like:

```xml
<OurCustomAttribute Value="ProjectSpecificValue"/>
<OurCustomAttribute Value="ProjectSpecificValueTwo"/>
```

or similar, either in an `<ItemGroup>`, directly inside the `<Project>` element itself, or a near equivalent, and have it be transformed into something like:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute">
    <_Parameter1>ProjectSpecificValue-InvariantValue</_Parameter1>
    <_Parameter2>$(SomeProperty)</_Parameter2>
    <_Parameter3>$(SomeOtherProperty)-some-static-string</_Parameter3>
    <!-- ...etc... -->
  </AssemblyAttribute>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute">
    <_Parameter1>ProjectSpecificValueTwo-InvariantValue</_Parameter1>
    <_Parameter2>$(SomeProperty)</_Parameter2>
    <_Parameter3>$(SomeOtherProperty)-some-static-string</_Parameter3>
    <!-- ...etc... -->
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

We are using a Directory.Build.props, so some way of defining this behaviour in there would be ideal. Item transforms don't seem capable of this; I've seen from the docs that an inline Task could output items, but it's not clear to me how this could be (terse-ish-ly) invoked from the project file (custom Target somehow?), or if they would be picked up by the Targets which followed, or which `BeforeTarget` would need to be used here. We'd prefer not to have to create a custom task assembly for this.

Is this kind of parameterisation actually possible in MSBuild XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties and define the item inside of `Directory.Build.props`.

The important thing is that MSBuild performs multiple passes over the enitre project and its imports, meaning that for example it reads all the `PropertyGroup` elements before it processes all the `ItemGroup` elements. Since `Directory.Build.props` is imported near the top of the SDK and thus logically before your actual csproj content, you can define properties with defualt values in `Directory.Build.Props` and then also define the `ItemGroup` with your assembly attribute item in it in the same file - the property can then still be overwritten in the main `csproj` file.

For example consider a `MyCorp.ComponentNameAttribute` with a name and a description and also the target framework used:

`Directory.Build.props`:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Default these properties to the name of the project file being built without the extension (.csproj) -->
    <MyCorpComponentName>$(MSBuildProjectName)</MyCorpComponentName>
    <MyCorpComponentDescription>$(MSBuildProjectName)</MyCorpComponentDescription>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="MyCorp.ComponentNameAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>$(MyCorpComponentName)</_Parameter1>
      <_Parameter2>$(MyCorpComponentDescription)</_Parameter2>
      <_Parameter3>$(MyCorpComponentDotNetVersion)</_Parameter3>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And `ComponentA.csproj` could then set:

```
<Project Sdk="...">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- MyCorpComponentName is 'ComponentA' by default, let's say this project doesn't change that -->
    <MyCorpComponentDescription>This component performs important business logic in the domain of XYZ</MyCorpComponentDescription>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If you want to modify properties AFTER the project content has been set, you can use `Directory.Build.targets` to have more property groups with conditions on them or when you need to rely on other properties that are set during the project evaluation as defaults (e.g. the `TargetFramework` is not yet known when processing `Directory.Build.props` but should be there when `Directory.Build.targets` is evaluated).

`Directory.Build.targets`:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyCorpComponentDotNetVersion Condition="'$(MyCorpComponentDotNetVersion )' == ''">$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</MyCorpComponentDotNetVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Updated the question, sorry; I originally missed the detail that we may need to apply this custom attribute more than once.

Answer (score 0):

### Single Value Attribute

The `Directory.Build.props` is auto imported very early -- before the body of the .csproj file and even before the 'standard' properties are defined. Unless you have a specific need, I suggest avoid using the `Directory.Build.props` file and favor using the `Directory.Build.targets` file.

The `.props` and `.targets` files are plain MSBuild files and can contain any valid MSBuild content. `.props` is not restricted to properties and items and `.targets` is not restricted to targets.

Items don't take parameters but `Include` values and values for metadata will be evaluated for property expansion.

The support for the `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute` can be placed in one file (e.g. `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute.targets`) that is then [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022)ed in the auto imported `Directory.Build.targets`. Don't copy/paste into each .csproj file.

```xml
<!-- Directory.Build.targets -->
<Project>
  <Import Project="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute.targets" />
</Project>
```

The `_Parameter1`, `_Parameter2`, and `_Parameter3` metadata on the `AssemblyAttribute` item will be matched to parameters of a constructor of the your `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute` type. Changes to the constructor for the `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute` type may require changes to the `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute.targets` file.
(You don't show the constructor. I'll assume from your `AssemblyAttribute` item example that the constructor has three parameters.)

You can set a property for the `ProjectSpecificValue` value in the .csproj and that property will be available to use in the code from the `Directory.Build.targets`.

The `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute.targets` file may be like the following:

```xml
<!-- Namespace.OurCustomAttribute.targets -->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectDefaultValue>$(MSBuildProjectName)</ProjectDefaultValue>
    <ProjectSpecificValue Condition="'$(ProjectSpecificValue)' == ''">$(ProjectDefaultValue)</ProjectSpecificValue>

    <SomeProperty Condition="'$(SomeProperty)' == ''">SomeDefaultValue</SomeProperty>

    <SomeOtherProperty Condition="'$(SomeOtherProperty)' == ''">SomeOtherDefaultValue</SomeOtherProperty>

    <_Parameter1Value>$(ProjectSpecificValue)-InvariantValue</_Parameter1Value>
    <_Parameter2Value>$(SomeProperty)</_Parameter2Value>
    <_Parameter3Value>$(SomeOtherProperty)-some-static-string</_Parameter3Value>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>$(_Parameter1Value)</_Parameter1>
      <_Parameter2>$(_Parameter2Value)</_Parameter2>
      <_Parameter3>$(_Parameter3Value)</_Parameter3>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  <ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In a .csproj file you would define the `$(ProjectSpecificValue)` property in a new or existing `PropertyGroup`.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectSpecificValue>ValueForThisProject</ProjectSpecificValue>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Because the `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute.targets` file is coupled to the code for the Attribute, it may be a good idea to publish or share the `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute.targets` file with the Attribute's assembly file.

### Multi-value Attribute

The above assumes a single value custom attribute that will be applied to all assemblies.

Item collections allow duplicates. The value used for the `Include` (which will be the `Identity` metadata) is not a unique key. Further items with the same `Identity` but differences in other metadata are not considered to be duplicates.

The following example provides two values for the `Namespace.OurCustomAttribute` attribute.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>foo</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>bar</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  <ItemGroup>
```

MSBuild uses the `@(AssemblyAttribute)` item collection to generate a code file that sets the assembly attributes.

```cs
[assembly:Namespace.OurCustomAttribute("foo")]
[assembly:Namespace.OurCustomAttribute("bar")]
```

For project specific values that don't depend on the build and don't change often it may be best to set the attribute in code yourself.

```cs
[assembly:Namespace.OurCustomAttribute("ProjectSpecificValue")]
```

(Note that this code doesn't need to be in a file named `AssemblyInfo.cs`. An assembly attribute can be added to any code file.)

You can mix using both `@(AssemblyAttribute)` and attribute values set in code.

### Using a Task

Writing a task for setting an individual value probably doesn't make sense.

A task can't access properties and items. A property or item can be passed to a task as a parameter and an [`Output` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/output-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) can be added to map a task output value.

If a `SetOurCustomAttribute` task where created, its usage might look something like the following.

```xml
  <Target Name="Example" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <SetOurCustomAttribute Value="ProjectSpecificValue">
      <Output TaskParameter="OutputItem" ItemName="AssemblyAttribute" />
    </SetOurCustomAttribute>
  </Target>
```

In terms of terseness, that's not much of an improvement over using an `ItemGroup`. Additionally an `ItemGroup` is not limited to only being used within a target.

A task might make sense if there is a set of build data used to compute a set of values for the attribute. Within the task a new `ITaskItem[]` would be created and populated. An `Output` element would be needed to map an output parameter for the `ITaskItem[]` to `AssemblyAttribute`.

Comment: Updated the question, sorry; I originally missed the detail that we may need to apply this custom attribute more than once.

Comment: The number of instances of the custom attribute will vary per assembly? But the values for the custom attribute are dependent on the specific run of the build process?

Comment: Zero, one, or multiple instances of the custom attribute, yes. Arguments passed to its constructor are a mix of what is supplied to the build via properties and values unique to each project which don't change often. Where the custom is applied more than once there will be different project-specific values for each instance.

Comment: A multi-value assembly attribute is very unusual and I can't imagine a use case for it.

Comment: Instances of the custom attribute can be added both via the `AssemblyAttribute` item collection and via code. The same `Identity` can be added to `AssemblyAttribute` multiple times, e.g. `<AssemblyAttribute Include="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute" _Parameter1="Value0"/><AssemblyAttribute Include="Namespace.OurCustomAttribute" _Parameter1="Value1"/>`. For project specific values that don't depend on the build and don't change often it may be best to add a .cs code file, e.g. with content like `[assembly:Namespace.OurCustomAttribute("ProjectSpecificValue")]`. (I'll update my answer.)

Comment: Multi-instance assembly attributes aren't unprecedented, eg. `[InternalsVisibleTo]` in particular. I agree the custom one we've inherited here is a bit out of the ordinary though.

Comment: Good point about `InternalsVisibleTo`